# Google Chrome App uploaded on app store but not show Add to Chrome Button

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have create a chrome app and uploaded on google store but not show chrome Add button.

[Image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqX68.png) [Image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiPpq.png)

---

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "eSignPanda",
    "version": "2.0",
    "description": "This app enables you to access eSignPanda",
    "icons": {
        "128": "favicon.png"
    },
    "app":{
        "urls": ["https://www.esignpanda.com/"],
        "launch":{
            "web_url": "https://www.esignpanda.com/#/ChromAppDriveApp"
        }
    },
    "offline_enabled": true
}
```

Comment: IIRC Chrome stopped supporting apps that only launch a web site because this is basically a bookmark, not a real app.

Comment: Thanks I got your point Lets try me to this in other way.